# Not able to send encrypted data through tcp socket in c

Tags: sockets, encryption, tcp, openssl

I am encrypting data in client.c and sending it to server.c. However when i am printing the size of the encrypted data in client.c it's 256 whereas on server.c it's printing some number between 1 and 256. Thus i am not able to send encrypted data over through the socket. How to resolve this ?

client.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char pub[100000],pri[100000];

void read_file(char *fnm,char *data)
{
    int length;
    FILE *f=fopen(fnm,"rb");

    if(f)
    {
        fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
        length=ftell(f);
        fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
        fread(data,1,length,f);
        fclose(f);
    }
}

int padding = RSA_PKCS1_PADDING;

RSA * createRSA(unsigned char * key,int public) {
    RSA *rsa= NULL;
    BIO *keybio;
    keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf(key, -1);
    if (keybio==NULL) {
        printf( "Failed to create key BIO");
        return 0;
    }
    if(public) {
        rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(keybio, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else {
        rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keybio, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
    }
    if(rsa == NULL) {
        printf("Could not create RSA\n");
    }
    return rsa;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd,portno,n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[100000],arg3[100000],encrypt[100000],decrypt[100000];

    //file name,IP,port number,it's private key,other client public key
    //use public key to encrypt
    //private key to decrypt
    //so we can make char arrays and read who file data into them

    read_file(argv[3],pri);
    read_file(argv[4],pub);

    RSA *rpub = createRSA((unsigned char*)pub,1);
    RSA *rpri = createRSA((unsigned char*)pri,0);

    if(argc<5)
    {
        error("Enter all details");
    }

    portno = atoi(argv[2]);

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(sockfd<0)
        error("Error opening socket");

    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

    if(server==NULL)
    {
        error("No such host");
    }

    bzero((char*) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    bcopy((char*)server->h_addr,(char*)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);

    serv_addr.sin_port=htons(portno);

    if(connect(sockfd,&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
    {
        printf("Error connecting\n");
    }

    //first send it's own message and then receive message from server
    // Do the encryption of own message before sending
    //decrypt the message received from server 


    printf("Please enter the message\n");
    bzero(buffer,100000);
    fgets(buffer,100000-1,stdin);


    //encrypt the buffer data

    int encrypted_len = RSA_public_encrypt(strlen(buffer),buffer,encrypt,rpub,padding);

    //send the encrypted data

    printf("%d\n", encrypted_len);

    if(encrypted_len==-1)
    {
        printf("Encryption failed\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //encrypt = buffer;

    n=write(sockfd,encrypt,encrypted_len);

    if(n<0)
    {
            printf("Error writing to socket\n");
            return 0;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

server.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd,newsockfd[2],portno,clilen;
    char buffer[2][100000];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr,cli_addr;
    int n;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Error, no port provided\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(sockfd < 0)
    {
        error("Error opening socket\n");
    }

    bzero((char*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    portno=atoi(argv[1]);

    serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port=htons(portno);

    if( bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error on binding\n");
        return 0;
    }

    listen(sockfd,5);
    clilen=sizeof(cli_addr);

    
    newsockfd[0]=accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

    bzero(buffer,100000);

    n=read(newsockfd[0],buffer[0],100000-1);


    printf("%d\n", strlen(buffer[0]));

    //server part if completed

    return 0;
}
```

Note : to run client.c you need to provide localhost, port number,private key, public key as command line parameter. Whereas to run server.c only port number is required.

Comment: There's no guarantee (either in TCP or in OpenSSL) that you will receive all of the sent bytes via single call to `read()`.  You need to keep calling `read()` until you've received all the bytes you expected to get (or until `read()` returns 0, indicating that the connection has been closed)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner it's returning 0 after reading 80 to 110 bytes even if i am using read in loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However when i am printing the size of the encrypted data in client.c it's 256 whereas on server.c it's printing some number between 1 and 256.

What the server is printing is not *the size of the encrypted data*, it's `strlen(buffer[0])`; you overlook that encrypted data can contain *null characters*, so it's inappropriate to apply `strlen`.

---

As suggested here's the also helpful comment by Jeremy Friesner:

*There's no guarantee (either in TCP or in OpenSSL) that you will receive all of the sent bytes via single call to `read()`.  You need to keep calling `read()` until you've received all the bytes you expected to get (or until `read()` returns 0, indicating that the connection has been closed)*

Comment: When i decrypted in server it didn't displayed the message some times whereas sometimes it did displayed.

Comment: At the moment, nobody knows whether errors lie in a truncated transmission or elsewhere. The first step is to determine the true amount of received data, which isn't possible with `strlen`.

Comment: How to know size of encryption ? Is it 256 ? But then different input data might get encrypted to larger size ?

Comment: At first, it's important to just observe whether the amount of received data really differs from the amount of sent data, so just arrange your server code so that the true amount is printed.

Comment: I am able to print the data when i am reading upto 256 bytes . But if my previous message is longer than current message then some part of previous message is also printed (when i am running the code in loop). How to avoid it ?

Comment: Does that mean that the problem described in the question post is solved and you now have a different problem?

Comment: Armali, that above problem is also solved. If you add  Jeremy Friesner  comment as quote in your answer, then it will be good since both of you helped me.

Comment: Regarding the new problem (or did you mean that with _also solved_?): Do you send the different messages over the same connection, and if yes, how does the server recognize the end of a message?

Comment: Following is all i did  :  I read the messages send for 256 bytes since encryption in TCP is 256 bytes (suggested by Jeremy and you since data might not necessarily end with '\0') .  Before transferring the data to char array i initialized it to zero. It removed the last problem where  some portion of previous message was also printed after decryption in server side (But it was not part of question, but i am writing it so that anyone having related problem can read it here).